# What is causing this chain clicking noise?

Tags: chain, cassette, noise

The click only happens when the chain is moving in certain locations. If the gear is low it happens every rotation and if the gear is high it happens 2 or 3 times per rotation of the pedal.

I am trying to figure out if the chain is stretched or somthing is wrong with the cassette.

To explain this more I have uploaded a demostration video of how it sounds.

This happens on multiple gears at different locations on the chain. It happens more than once every turn of the pedal depending on the gear.

Update: measured chain for stretching and looks like no issues.

UPDATE: Fixed by adjusting the cable tension using rear barrel adjuster about half a turn.

Comment: Full marks for trying to make a vid of the problem. But ... it would be much easier to diagnose if you just turn the pedals steadily and avoid the back pedalling and free-wheeling ratchet noises. The latter can be achieved by (another person) keeping a finger on the rim to stop the wheel from spinning fast.

Comment: There is a "hiccup" on 0:41-0:42. And seems you try to repeat it on 0:45-0:47.  You really see the link not attach to the tooth but "slide in" to make the noise. I will use color marker to mark all chain link that show this symptoms.  Then assess the problem later (to check it is only the link show the problem, or it is repetitive every N-cycle not due link)

Comment: Is this happening on each gear? Have you tried adjusting gears?

Comment: it happens on 100% of gears I tried - 6 of 11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things I see:

1. I think your derailleur is a bit out of adjustment and is "leaning" towards the lower gears.  It's grabbing on the ramps of the lower gear as it goes by.
2. Your B screw adjustment is a bit too far away from the cassette.  I would try to get it within a link or link and half.  It looks from the video that you are about 2-3 links away.  See section 4 of this link: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/derailer-adjustment.html

Lastly, is it possible that 9 speed chain (or less) is on that 10 speed cassette?  If the chain is too wide, it would have the same symptoms (grabbing the ramps)

Comment: This is the correct answer. For anyone who doesn't see it, look very close at the point where the chain first touches the cassette, at 00:15 to 00:17 of the video posted. You can clearly see the chain catch the ramp of the next highest sprocket, then drop back onto the correct sprocket again, creating the problematic noise. The solution is to correctly adjust the deraillaur (let out a _tiny_ bit of tension)

Comment: Thanks @Lachlan its fixed by adjusting the cable tension.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird!  It sounds like slack being taken up on the cranks, but the image doesn't match that.

Try separating the components - take the wheel out, can you feel any notchiness on spinning the cassette?

*Diagnostic Ideas:*

- Take the chain off, and feel it for stiff or grotty link.  Then clean it and measure it for wear.
- While chain is off, inspect the jockey wheels for wear, and feel around for any notchiness.
- Now with your chain clean but not lubed, assemble it lightly so the chain is not on the chainrings... now pull the chain by hand and see if you can replicate the noise.
- Do the same again with chain on cassette only and leaving out the jockey wheels.

Try and halve the problem and then see which side the symptom goes to.

BTW remember to relube chain once you reassemble.

Comment: This is too big for a comment, but isn't really an answer.  More of suggestions on how to narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have had a problem with a regular clicking noise coming from the chain - it has been either a stiff link (which goes as the chain loosens up through use) or a split pin on the chain ie. the pin has detached from one side of the chain. It can be hard to spot but worth examining for.

Comment: It happens on different chain link depending on the gear.